# how to get users by query in facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

In facebook UI when I type 'people who like bill gates and like a.r. rahman' in search box it giving users list who likes both bill and rahman. But how can I get these users through graph api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to implement this with the Graph API. Public Post Search was removed and the Graph Search is only available on facebook.com.